# Currying React Parent Functions for Child

Tags: reactjs, currying

I am trying to curry a parent function and be able to pass a parameter to the function in the child. The following code is not working for me.

Within Parent:

```
  public onSavePerson = (person: Person) => value => {
    const result = { ...person, ...value };
    this.props.store.savePerson({ ...person, ...value });
  };

render() {
 .....
   <DropdownButton
     items={statuses}
     itemRender={item => humanizeText(item)}
     onClick={() => this.onSavePerson(row)}
     intentRender={item => getStatusIntent(item)}
     initialText={row.status}
   />
.....
```

Child:

```
export const DropdownButton = props => {
  const { items, itemRender, onClick, intentRender, initialText } = props;
  return (
    <Popover
      content={
        <Menu>
          {items.map((item, i) => (
            <Menu.Item text={itemRender(item)} onClick={onClick(item)} intent={intentRender(item)} key={i} />
          ))}
        </Menu>
      }
      position={Position.BOTTOM}>
      <Button text={humanizeText(initialText)} intent={intentRender && intentRender(initialText)} />
    </Popover>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by first calling the curried function and then passing in the parameter

```
        <Menu>
          {items.map((item, i) => (
            <Menu.Item text={itemRender(item)} onClick={onClick()(item)} intent={intentRender(item)} key={i} />
          ))}
        </Menu>
```

However, I later changed this to be simpler in the call